# Sharing common data to multiple Python files

Tags: python, python-import

I have multiple Python files which needs to share common data. 
For example,

```
Test1.py
Test2.py
Test3.py
```

Each test file must use same type of variable pattern like this,

```
inputVariables = [
    inputVariableDef(
        name='srv_ip',
        description='IP address of the server',
        value="xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    ),
    inputVariableDef(
        name='clnt_ip',
        description='IP address of the client',
        value="xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    ),
    inputVariableDef(
        name='count',
        description='Loop Count',
        value=10,
    ),
]
```

I need to pass same client & server ip addresses to all files at `value="xx.xxx.xxx.xx"`. To do that I have used the following method,

common.py:

```
server_ip = "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
client_ip = "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
```

and tried accessing by importing common.py in each test file like this:

test1.py:

```
from root.projectA.windows.lib import common
value = common.server_ip
```

But some how my application is not able to recognize the imported module `common` and says `common.server_ip` not found.

Is there any alternative way to solve this?

Directory Structure is like this:

```
root -> projectA -> windows -> lib -> common.py

root -> projectA -> windows -> testfiles -> test1.py
```

Comment: Where is `common.py` located? How do you import it? What error does python throw?

Comment: Please see my edit, It says **name common not defined**

Comment: We will also need the directory structure, where `common.py` is located, where the script is located where you call it from. And what exactly is `absolutepath` ?

Comment: That's means that `common` is not defined. Have you defined `common` in `root.projectA.windows.lib`? Or does it say something else than `name common not defined`? The error message is important, it contains important information about what's wrong - read the error message to figure it out (and we also need to read the message if we're to help you).

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file inside lib? Also, could you copy past the stack trace?

Comment: Do you have `root` file in the $PYTHONPATH or `sys.path` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the folder containing common, `lib/` is declared as a module, and its parent is on the path.

Create a file `__init__.py` inside the `lib/` directory. Your directory structure should look like this:

```
projectA/windows -> lib -> common.py
                 |      +> __init__.py
                 |
                 +> testfiles -> test1.py
```

The `__init__.py` file can be empty. This just tells python that the lib directory is a module named `lib`.

Then, in `test1.py`, you want this code at the start:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
thisdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
parentdir = "/".join(thisdir.split('/')[:-1])
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)

from lib import common
value = common.server_ip

print "IP is %s" % value
```

It will insert the parent directory of the file into the system path, and let Python find the `lib` module for importing. Please note that this code assumes a Unix path separator `/` - if you are running on Windows you'll probably need to change that.